# is it possible to grid a polyline shape javaFX

Tags: for-loop, javafx, grid

So I am presently making a game in javaFX and the board has the shape of a hexagon. I used polyline and gave it fixed points as shown below.

```
    // Create a hexagon
    Polyline hexagon = new Polyline(400.0,600.0,
                                    700.0,600.0,
                                    800.0,400.0, 
                                    700.0,200.0,
                                    400.0,200.0,
                                    300.0,400.0,
                                    400.0,600.0
                                    );
        hexagon.setFill(Color.BLACK);
        hexagon.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
```

I get this output

[image: output]

The problem I am having is trying to grid this shape. could someone please show me how to grid a polyline import? or would I be better off create a hexagon from a for loop with the grid built in? if so could you tell me the best way possible to make a hexagon shape from a for loop? thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll never all values to be integral, since the height of the polygon is

```
(width * sqrt(3)) / 2
```

Your shape may look like a regular hexagon, however it isn't one, which becomes obvious once you create a grid from those shapes.

The simplest way of creating this would be using polar coordinates with an origin at the center of the polygon and convert them to cartesian coordinates. Furthermore I recommend using `Polygon` instead of `Polyline`, since this shape is automatically closed.

For calculating the grid positions note that you can just place the hexagons below each other with a offset equal to the hexagon's height (`radius * sqrt(3)`) in vertical direction. In horizontal direction the difference in x coordinates is `(3/2) * radius`, since the next hexagon's leftmost point is aligned with the bottom right or top right point of the previous hexagon. The y coordinate is altered by half the height of the hexagon (alternating up and down).

```
private final static double HEX_RAD_DELTA = Math.PI / 3;

public static Polygon createHexagon(double centerX, double centerY, double radius, Paint fill) {
    Polygon hex = new Polygon();

    // comparing to 6 is enough to ensure every angle is used once here
    // since (5/6) * 2 * PI < 6 < 2 * PI
    for (double rad = 0; rad < 6; rad += HEX_RAD_DELTA) {
        hex.getPoints().addAll(Math.cos(rad) * radius + centerX, Math.sin(rad) * radius + centerY);
    }

    hex.setFill(fill);
    hex.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
    return hex;
}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    Color[] fills = new Color[] {
        Color.RED,
        Color.BLUE,
        Color.LIME,
        Color.ORANGE,
        Color.TURQUOISE,
        Color.BROWN,
        Color.YELLOW
    };

    final double radius = 50;
    final double dY = radius * Math.sqrt(3) / 2;

    Pane root = new Pane();
    for (int y = 0, colorIndex = 0; y < 10; y++) {
        double offsetY  = 2 * dY * y + 50;
        for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++, colorIndex = (colorIndex + 1) % fills.length) {
            root.getChildren().add(createHexagon(
                    1.5 * radius * x + 50,
                    (x & 1) == 0 ? offsetY : offsetY + dY,
                    radius,
                    fills[colorIndex]));
        }
    }

    Scene scene = new Scene(root);

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

Comment: thanks very much that was very well explained its a working progress trying to get my head around 4 loops. i really do appreciate the help.